# CocoaLibSpotify - SPSearch Returns 0 Artists via KVO for @"a"

Tags: spotify, cocoalibspotify-2.0, libspotify

SPSearch was working as expected, initialized as:

```
SPSearch* new_search = [[SPSearch alloc] initWithSearchQuery: search_string
                                                    pageSize: 50
                                                   inSession: active_session
                                                        type: SP_SEARCH_SUGGEST];
```

I then have KVO set up for @"artists" on the SPSearch instance. This is done by way of a category that has the instance observe itself for changes in @"artists" (and others). After new_search is instantiated, [new_search setDelegate: searchController] is called, which causes the SPSearch instance to call [searchController setArtists: artists_array] when KVO becomes aware of the update.

This was all working perfectly until I updated Xcode. As far as I can tell, nothing else changed.

Now, any search (such as @"a", but not limited to that) returns 0 artists in the array provided via KVO notification.

SPSession instance.connectionState is SP_CONNECTION_STATE_LOGGED_IN when the search is created. As far as I can tell, everything is being properly instantiated, logged in, etc.

What could possibly be going on that causes search to always return no results? What are some places I might start investigating to figure out what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

CocoaLibSpotify ships with a bunch of unit tests, which includes testing of `SPSearch`. Please run these tests (details in the readme) - if the search tests pass, have a look at how they're implemented. Your solution sounds like it could cause problems in world of ARC.

Comment: Communication on IRC post unit testing lead to the conclusion that live search and artist and album meta data are not working properly. Resolution pending. Standard search works; observing self does not seem to be a problem for ARC, but keeping that in mind as a potential future problem. Will update as I learn more.